# How to cycle thru items in print composer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

In print composer I have many items placed on the "paper".  These items include borders, one map, bar scale, logo and an arrow.  When the items overlap each other I am only able to select the item on top.  If I want the item below I have to select the first item and send it to the back.  Is there an easier way to select the item below another, without having to send the first item to the back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in QGIS 2.2 and later versions there's a few options for selecting items behind other items:

- Holding "ctrl" while selecting items will progressively select the next item below in the stack with each mouse click
- Pressing ctrl+alt+[ or ctrl+alt+] selects the next item above or below the currently selected item
- From the edit menu, choose "select next item above" or "select next item below"
- From the edit menu, you can invert a selection by choosing "invert selection"